# How to count number of entries on a dataset based on given conditions and assign those results into a matrix using for loops?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have a dataset with 50 unique entries, and each entries has some hundreds of in favor and against votes for each of those elements (which I set as 1 and 0). I want to calculate the number of 1s and 0s per element.

I know that if I subset each entries I can find the counts I am looking for, but since there're several other conditions I want to count too, making a for loop would save me time.

So I did:

```
matrix_name <- matrix(NA, ncol = 6, nrow = 50) 
colnames(matrix_name) <- c(xyz)
# I have the first column for the entries, the second for "Yes", the third for "No", and the remaining some extra conditions

matrix_entries <- unique(df$entries)
names(matrix_name[,]) <- matrix_entries

for(i in 1:50){
  matrix_name[i] <- matrix_entries[i]
}
```

With this I am able to assign the entry name in the first column, but I can't proceed with the counting (that would go in the remaining columns) using a loop (which I would substitute the bunch of NAs that I have).

What I did to count the number of Yes and No for each entry was:

```
count(subset(df, entry == "entry #1" & vote == "1"))
count(subset(df, entry == "entry #1" & vote == "0"))
```

But I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to count those entries, and how to use a for loop in this situation.

I appreciate your time for replying.

Edit: Here goes the subset with relevant information:

```
structure(list(`Entry;Name;Vote` = c("Entry #1;Alex;0", "Entry #1;John;0", 
"Entry #1;Tom;1", "Entry #1;Phillip;0", "Entry #1;Mary;0", "Entry #1;Anna;0", 
"Entry #1;Peter;0", "Entry #1;Erika;1", "Entry #1;Louise;0", 
"Entry #1;Arthur;0")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please post a small reproducible subset of `df`. Just a couple entries and a few votes each should be plenty. `dput(df[1:10, ])` would give the first 10 rows in a copy/pasteable format. Choose a suitable subset.

Comment: What is `xyz` ?

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you, I just added in the original post.

Comment: @Julien it is a random entry, but in the original script I wrote the name of all rows I am using